# magento 404 error when display a product

Tags: magento-1.8, product, 404-page

In my magento website and since this morning when I open a page to display a product it shows me a 404 not found page (and for the group deals page it's empty and I can't even pass an order).

I don't know what it causes this problem because it was working yesterday.

PS: All the products display a 404 not found page and my magento version is 1.8.1

Comment: Please reindex and refresh cache. Then forget old url. Take products via category.

Comment: Take a look at the following it might be helpful,




  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2184796/magento-product-page-404-error

Comment: I refresh cache, check the Url Rewrite Section and the 'report_event_types' table but the same problem

Comment: Is product is enabled, visible in frontend and not out of stock?

Comment: The product is enable, visible and not out of stock but in frontend it shows that the product is sold out (even the quantity in backend is over 0)